# Unable to use Laravel Eloquent findOrFail method using call_user_func_array function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have searched how to use **call_user_func_arra**y with Eloquent method. But didn't find any clue about it.
I want to make my code more flexible using call_user_func_array method in my Eloquent query.

**Code not working:-**

```
$object = call_user_func_array($this->object_type . '::findOrFail', [$this->object_slug]);
```

**Error:-**

*ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Friendship' not found.*

But if I am not using call_user_func_array method, then my below code is running fine:-

```
$object = Friendship::find($this->object_slug);
```

Please guide me whether static callback method  be used in call_user_func_array function? If not then please suggest any alternate approach.

---

**Problem Solved:-**

**call_user_func_array** method don't care about `use namespaces`. So in case of namespaces add full path of class.

**Updated code:-**

`call_user_func_array('\SiteApp\Friendship\\' . $this->object_type . '::findOrFail', [$this->object_slug]);`

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Are you working with namespaces?

Comment: For what reasons are you using `call_user_func_array`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I m using namespace. Also I have already added that friendship class in my current class. `use SiteApp\Friendship\Friendship`

Comment: @ollieread bcoz i have to Find data in many Eloquent models dymanically.

Comment: I believe the problem is that `call_user_func_array` doesn't care about `use` statements. Can you verify by using `call_user_func_array('\SiteApp\Friendship\' . $this->object_type . '::findOrFail', [$this->object_slug]);`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter thanks..You have saved my day...wanna buy 1 beer 4 U :)

Comment: @Bit_hunter Haha you're welcome. I'd sure love a beer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `call_user_func_array()` doesn't care about `use` statements for importing classes so you have to use the fully qualified class name:

```
call_user_func_array('\SiteApp\Friendship\Friendship::findOrFail', [$this->object_slug]);
```

It depends on your case but the simplest would probably be to store the full name in `$this->object_type`.

```
// $this->object_type = '\SiteApp\Friendship\Friendship';
call_user_func_array($this->object_type . '::findOrFail', [$this->object_slug]);
```